# Are RTMFP Flash games the new big thing?

Tags: flash, multiplayer, peer-to-peer

After watching (and playing) [HaxBall](http://www.haxball.com/), I can imagine that RTMFP (or any other real time multiplayer flash based technology) games will be the new big thing, replacing social games (cafeworld, etc).

What do you think about it? Is now the right moment to dedicate some time to learn how this technology works and how can it be used at its full potential?

Just your two cents.

Comment: I had to RTFA to know that RTMFP meant :P

Comment: What does the P mean? I got as far as real-time multiplayer flash..and can you edit the title?

Comment: Trolling? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Media_Flow_Protocol

Comment: I don't think he was trolling, it's probably not a very common acronym.

Comment: speculative questions are off-topic here. They are usually not proper questions and tend to produce opinions and emotion rather than answers. http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/275/speculative-questions-off-topic

Answer (score 2):

Many browser games are single player. Of the multiplayer ones, there are lots of "social" ones (e.g. on Facebook), letting you play with your friends. Since your friends aren't online at the same time as you, these games are typically asynchronous — you play a bit, then they play a bit, then you play a bit. There are also some synchronous games — you and they play at the same time. These are common on XBox and PC not as common in the browser. You typically play these games with strangers.

I can't say it's the next big thing but the synchronous realtime games seem to be uncommon when it comes to browser games. Maybe people don't like playing with strangers. There are a few out there though. For example, there's [Realm of the Mad God](http://www.realmofthemadgod.com/), which has hundreds of players online at once. (Disclaimer: the authors are friends of mine.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything about the game you linked, or the concept of "real time Flash-based multiplayer" games in general, that would distinguish them in any kind of revolutionary fashion from the glut of Flash-based games out there already, multiplayer or not. Nor do I see them as being all that distinct from most casual or social games that exist as well.

That said, just because there is nothing mind-blowingly revolutionary about them doesn't mean they are a dead end. If you are interested in the platform, understand the advantages and disadvantages of that platform (from both a technical and marketing perspective) and can make you game idea work within that context then by all means, invest some time in learning the technology.

Comment: Then you didnt play the game.

Comment: In fact, I did. Perhaps you could elaborate on what I missed that makes you think the technology is so revolutionary?

Comment: Im not saying the technology is revolutionary, im saying its not exploited. I said you dindt play the game cuz you literally said that you didnt see a real time flash based multiplayer game.

Comment: Josh, this might not be "revolutionary", but this is a level of real time interaction that I've never seen before in a flash game. Perhaps I just don't play enough flash games?

Comment: Olhovsky, thats exactly what Im talking about, I do play Flash games, and this kind of real time experience is just not outthere.

Comment: I guess I just don't know enough about Flash-based games to see that this is all that interesting (as from a technology-agnostic perspective it looks old hat). That being what it is, like I said, if it looks useful to you then learn it -- there's no reason not to, as it's obviously functional and learning new things can rarely harm you as a developer.